# Remove duplicate attributes from a collection Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For some strange reason, my collection (returned from query) is showing duplicate attribute `4 times` exactly. Is there a way to remove duplicate or repeated attributes.

```
#attributes: array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Ram Inden"
        "features" => "2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4"
```

In this collection, the features attributes only should have `2,3,4` but it's repeated four times, and I don't know why. In my database it's only `2,3,4`.

Another thing, this thing only appears at a Live server, my localhost works fine.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: show your code, add some details that we can try to help you. Or you just need to remove duplicates???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php explode,array_uniqe,join function

```
 $collection = collect([
            "name" => "Ram Inden",
            "features" => "2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4"
        ]);

        $unique = join(',', array_unique(explode(',', $collection['features'])));

        $collection['features'] = $unique;

        return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the collection you could eliminate the duplicates in the following way:

```
$collection = collect([
    "name" => "Ram Inden",
    "features" => "2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4"
]);

$str = $collection['features'];  
$collection->prepend(implode(',',array_unique(explode(',', $str))) ,'features');

 return $collection;
```